# Sleep method and maximize windows in java selenium not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ChromeLaunch2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
        

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");

        // Maximize the window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();  // This maximizes the browser window
        
        // Other actions or code here
        
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

The code aboves should open the facebook and call the sleep thread for 10 seconds and maximize windows.